Actions of the circle on the compact interval
Does there exists a non-trivial faithful action of $S^1$ on $[0,1]$ (i.e. by homeomorphisms)?
My naive guess would be no, but I can't prove it. Here are some thoughts I had:

Since $S^1$ is connected and $\mathrm{Homeo}([0,1])$ has two components it must act via orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$.
Any homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ preserves the boundary, hence induces a homemorphism $\frac{[0,1]}{0\sim 1} = S^1 \to S^1 = \frac{[0,1]}{0\sim 1}$. We can mix quotient and product topology for these spaces as they are compact manifolds, hence we get a group action $f \colon S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ and the map $\mathrm{exp} \colon [0,1] \to S^1$ is equivariant. On the standard basis for fundamental groups the induced map $f_*$ is given by $\mathbb Z^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto (\pm y) \in \mathbb Z$, so it is not the canonical group action of $S^1$ on itself...

I don't know if these observations lead to anything, maybe there even exists such an action of $S^1$ on $[0,1]$. Can someone help me?

I am quite sure it was asked and answered before: the only nontrivial finite order self-homeomorphisms of intervals are involutions.

See for instance my answer here.

Let $f$ be a nontrivial, orientation preserving (that is, increasing) homeomorphism of $[0,1]$. Then without loss of generality, there is some $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) < x$. Since $f$ is increasing, $f^2(x) < f(x)$, and inductively, $f^n(x) < x$ for all $n$. Then any such $f$ cannot be finite order. Since $S^1$ is torsion free, it admits no faithful homormophism $S^1 \to \text{Homeo}([0,1])$.
Furthermore, the finite order points are dense in $S^1$, so we can in fact conclude that the trivial map is only (continuous) homomorphism. This same idea can be extended to possibly non-continuous homomorphisms without too much extra work (see the comment by Moishe Kohan).
